# Why isn't sorted() working when I try to sort the values in my dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary `article_counter = {"Title1": {'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'A': 2}}` and I'm trying to sort the counter so it becomes `{"Title1": {'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1}}`

I tried using this, but the values weren't getting sorted

```
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(article_counter.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1][1], x[1][0])), reverse=True)
```

but when I do this it works just fine

```
for i in article_counter.items():
    sorted_dict[i[0]] = sorted(i[1], key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Please, post [mre] that demonstrate your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your slicing was incorrect, `reverse=True` in the wrong position

```
article_counter = {'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'A': 2}


sorted_dict = dict(sorted(article_counter.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
```

Output: `{'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1}`

##### in a nested dictionary

```
article_counter = {"Title1": {'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'A': 2}}

sorted_dict = {k: dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])))
               for k, d in article_counter.items()}
```

Output: `{'Title1': {'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1}}`

Comment: Its more like article_counter = {"Title1": {'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'A': 2}} and I want it to sort so it show up as {"Title1": {'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'B': 1}} if that makes sense

Comment: @JosephHong same logic, see update

Comment: I got some errors, but I managed to figure it out, Thank you!